# How to stop systemd.tmfiles-clean service command line

Tags: 18.04, kernel, services

The daily job to clean temp files is causing a crash (hard reboot necessary), how can I disable it? Which file do I need to modify and add "Disabled" in the configuration?

The exact message in the logs is:

```
systemd-udevd[483]: seq 7491 '/kernel/slab//:A-0000256/cgroup/filp(1880:systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service)' is taking a long time

systemd-udevd[483]: seq 7492 '/kernel/slab//:aA-000192/cgroup/dentry(1880:systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service)' is taking a long time
```

After that 2nd message, the system was unresponsive and required a switch off/on.

The graphical interface is xfce with minimal tools installed and pretty unstable too, so I'd rather do command lines/edit files manually.

Thanks for your help!

Greg

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the file systemd-tempfiles-clean.timer and changed the OnUnitActiveSec=1d to 60d

That should do until I find what's in the temp files that makes the Ubuntu to hang.